# Error on SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I got a recent problem. I just deploy my project on a server. The problem is that, after I log in, I get this error :

> Unable to open the physical file 
>   "C:\ClientPortal\App_Data\DataUi.mdf".
>   Operating system error 5: "5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason:
>   15105)".Cannot attach the file 'C:\ClientPortal\App_Data\DataUi.mdf'
>   as database 'ClientPortal'.

What should I do with my connection string ?

```
<connectionStrings>
  <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
  <add name="LocalSqlServer" 
       connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DataUi;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|DataUi.mdf;User Instance=true"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Thank you for helping .

Comment: `Operating system error 5` means: access denied. For some reason, you do not have the permission to access that file. Check your permissions on the directory in question and on the file itself

Comment: I know this is a problem . And we had also the same problems few months ago . But all the network service etc are well configured ...

Comment: Ok now I got this error :
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try allowing permissions for the file `"DataUi.mdf"` and its containing folder `"App_Data"` for the user `"SQL Server Service"`.

If it doesn't work try adding permissions for `"Network Service"` instead.

Comment: Ok now I got this error :
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with permissions  just

```
Provide modify privilege for folder C:\ClientPortal\App_Data 
Makesure mdf file have modify privilege and then
Attach the db again
```

Also I found this article. Please try [this article](http://tonythetester.blogspot.com/2008/08/unable-to-open-physical-file.html) if above way not working

Comment: And SQL server is also installed !

Comment: is both your folder and mdf file have permissions?

Comment: Ok now I got this error :
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: probobly it is best to chase your error. the error you getting now, i found it here http://ryan.rawswift.com/2010/03/29/a-connection-attempt-failed-because-the-connected-party-did-not-properly-respond/

Answer (score 0):

First verify which user is running your SQL services, then allow write permission to that user on your file "DataUi.mdf". If your SQL services is running with "Network Services" then allow write permission to "Network Services" or everyone.